# locate: regex repetition postfix operator doesn't work with --regextype emacs

Tags: regular-expression, emacs, locate

I have some files whose the names are of the form `krita-NN.kra` where `NN` is a number having one to two digits. I wanted to `locate` them using Emacs regex. However, the [repetition postfix operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) (`\{n, m\}`, `\{n\}`) of Emacs regex doesn't seem to be accepted by `locate`. Specifically, both

- `locate --regex --regextype emacs 'krita-[0-9]\.kra$'`
- `locate --regex --regextype emacs 'krita-[0-9][0-9]\.kra$'`

return relevant results, but no regexes in the following work

- `locate --regex --regextype emacs 'krita-[0-9]\{1,2\}\.kra$` ;
- `locate --regex --regextype emacs 'krita-[0-9]\{1\}\.kra$`.

Even if curly brackets are not escaped.

**Question**: Does `locate` accept Emacs regex as it claims in the man page?

**NOTE**:

- This question is not looking for alternative solution *e.g.* with `find` or other regex type.
- `locate` version: `locate (GNU findutils) 4.7.0`

Comment: See `info  -n emacs locate`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, I should admit that I rarely go beyond man page, even if it told me to consult the Texinfo documentation... Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Stéphane Chazelas's suggestion, the Texinfo documentation (`info -n emacs locate`) doesn't specify repetition operator for `emacs` regex unlike [Emacs regex](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html). *A contrario*, the regex type `grep` supports it with the syntax I expected. Namely,

`locate --regex --regextype grep 'krita-[0-9]\{1,2\}\.kra$`

solves the issue.

Comment: Looks like `\{\}` were [added to GNU emacs regexps in 2000](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=fb4a568d44416da2db75525d8403228db0237145), but that was [not reflected in gnulib](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/regex.h?id=065b9a04c6d5ac1fea6b776fe4faa650d385e187#n218) as used by findutils (possibly by design to avoid breaking backward compatibility)

Comment: That is good to know, thanks.